# Most efficient way to compute difference between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-performance

I have a big table, partitioned by date, which is structured as follows:

**InTable:**

| Key | Date | Field1 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 09/02/2021 | ABC | 10 |
| key2 | 09/02/2021 | DEF | -4 |
| key3 | 09/02/2021 | GHI | 9 |
| key1 | 10/02/2021 | ABC | 30 |
| key2 | 10/02/2021 | DEFG | 6 |
| key4 | 10/02/2021 | LMN | 2 |

I want to output a table which is structured this way

**OutTable:**

| Key | Date | Field1 | Value T | Value T-1 | Daily Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 10/02/2021 | ABC | 30 | 10 | 20 |
| key2 | 10/02/2021 | DEFG | 6 | -4 | 10 |
| key3 | 10/02/2021 | GHI | 0 | 9 | -9 |
| key4 | 10/02/2021 | LMN | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Where I collapse on a date the current value, the value of the previous day and the difference between the two which have the same key, keeping also all the cases when a key is missing in either of the dates (for instance, key3 missing on 10/2 and key4 missing on 9/2).

Field1 is usually the same if key is the same. If they are different, the value of the most recent one has to be kept (as it is for key2 in the example).

As far as I know, this can be done:

- By self-joining the InTable on in1.key = in2.key and in1.day = in2.day-1
- By generating a sparse matrix with an union all between two dates and then peforming a group by on the key field
- By using the pivot construct

What is the most efficient and quicker way to do this job in Oracle?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your value columns seem to be switched.  T-1 has the current values and T the previous values.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for pointing out but I think that column values are correct. For instance, for key1, 30 is the value of 10/2 and 10 is the value of 9/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you could do (explanation after the code):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

with
  intable (key, date_, field1, value) as (
    select 'key1', to_date('09/02/2021'), 'ABC' , 10 from dual union all
    select 'key2', to_date('09/02/2021'), 'DEF' , -4 from dual union all
    select 'key3', to_date('09/02/2021'), 'GHI' ,  9 from dual union all
    select 'key1', to_date('10/02/2021'), 'ABC' , 30 from dual union all
    select 'key2', to_date('10/02/2021'), 'DEFG',  6 from dual union all
    select 'key4', to_date('10/02/2021'), 'LMN' ,  2 from dual
  )
, ref_date (dt) as (select to_date('10/02/2021') from dual)
, prep (key, field1, new_val, old_val) as (
    select i.key, 
           min(field1) keep (dense_rank last order by date_),
           nvl(min(case i.date_ when r.dt     then value end), 0),
           nvl(min(case i.date_ when r.dt - 1 then value end), 0)
    from   intable i cross join ref_date r
    where  date_ in (r.dt - 1, r.dt)
    group  by i.key, r.dt
  )
select p.key, r.dt as date_, p.field1,
       p.new_val, p.old_val, p.new_val - p.old_val as daily_diff
from   prep p cross join ref_date r
order  by key   --  If needed
;


KEY   DATE_       FIELD1  NEW_VAL  OLD_VAL  DAILY_DIFF
----  ----------  ------  -------  -------  ----------
key1  10/02/2021  ABC          30       10          20
key2  10/02/2021  DEFG          6       -4          10
key3  10/02/2021  GHI           0        9          -9
key4  10/02/2021  LMN           2        0           2
```

Explanation:

The `INTABLE` subquery in the `WITH` clause is just an easy way to simulate your input data (instead of creating a table and inserting in it, and then remembering to drop the table from my system). In real-life use, drop `INTABLE` from the query, and instead use your actual table and column names.

Note the `ALTER SESSION` statement I ran first - so I don't need to give a format model to `TO_DATE`. Note also that I changed the column name from `DATE` since `DATE` is a reserved keyword in Oracle. (Don't use double-quotes around column names to work around that constraint; just use a different name, like I did.)

You will see also that I used different column names in the output. Change them if you need to, but don't create column names with spaces in them, with dashes, etc. Use standard column names.

`REF_DATE` is also probably not needed; I use it to give the "report date" - but it is better if that is a bind variable. Alternatively, use a bind variable instead of the hard-coded value I gave, right there in that subquery (and ***keep*** `REF_DATE` in the `WITH` clause).

The main work is done in the `PREP` subquery. In fact, the optimizer will combine this subquery with the outer query (at the end of the code); I wrote it the way I did only to save some typing - this way I don't need to repeat the definitions of `OLD_VAL` and `NEW_VAL` to compute the difference. The optimized query (the result of the internal Oracle optimization) will only do one `SELECT`, and it will use "**sort** group by" (using the resulting sort for the `ORDER BY` of the outer query, in a single pass).

The query (the `PREP` subquery) filters just for the two dates needed for reporting - which will be helped tremendously by an **index** on column `DATE_`. Then the query uses standard aggregation (not analytic functions or any other features) - which will very likely make it faster than the alternatives.

It is not clear why you need the `DATE_` column in the output. It is not based on anything in the data - it just reports back the "reference date" you gave as input. I included it in case you do really need it (it's very inexpensive - I cross-join again to the scalar subquery `REF_DATE`), but if you don't need it, you can remove it from the main (outer) query, and you won't need the cross join, and you won't need an alias for `PREP` and the `P` qualifiers for the other columns.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer @mathguy. I created here the sqlfiddle just for anyone else interested with your solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09352/1

I have just one last doubt. Here is a solution using the pivot clause http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01142a/16 
Do you think that it is equivalent performance-wise to your solution or that might be a performance benefit to one solution compared to the other?
I'm unsure that this solution has to perform an extra nvl on field1 and so might be less fast, but I don't know if it uses a more efficient plan compared to a normal aggregation.

Comment: @sorrow - Pivoting is a form of aggregation; the way I wrote the query is essentially the way pivoting used to be done before Oracle introduced the `pivot` operator, and it is very likely that `pivot` is still implemented the same way. The Explain Plan will show the operation as "hash group by pivot". In any case, you have the real-life data, test both queries and compare them. Much better than guessing. :-) You WILL see a difference if the base table has more columns, since pivoting groups by ALL columns not mentioned in the `pivot` clause, not just by `key`. I just didn't want to assume.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions.  If you have data on all days or want the data on the previous date in the data:

```
select t.*,
       lag(value, 1, 0) over (partition by key, field order by date) as prev_value,
       (value - lag(value, 1, 0) over (partition by key, field order by date)) as diff
from t;
```

If values can skip dates and you really want the previous date, you can use a window function with a `range` window frame:

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (partition by key, field 
                        order by date
                        range between '1' day preceding and '1' day preceding
                       ) as prev_value,
       (value - 
        max(value) over (partition by key, field 
                        order by date
                        range between '1' day preceding and '1' day preceding
                       )
       ) as diff
from t;
```

This leaves the missing values as `NULL`.  You can use `COALESCE()` to assign values to them.

If you want to filter by day, you need to do that in the outer query:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(value) over (partition by key, field1 
                              order by day
                              range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' day preceding
                             ) as prev_value,
             (value - 
              max(value) over (partition by key, field1 
                               order by day
                              range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' day preceding
                             )
             ) as diff
      from InTable t
     ) t
where day = date '2021-02-10'
order by day asc;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/947a4/14) is a db<>fiddle.

If you want to prune the partitions, then you need to include the lagged rows in the subquery.  You can sue:

```
where day in (date '2021-02-10', date '2021-02-09')
```

in the subquery.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the answer.
If I run the query on the InTable, I think that it will return also record corresponding to 9/2, all having T-1 values set to 0 (or null if without coalesce). This can be of course fixed by filtering the output values, but I'm not entirely sure it is more efficient than, the union all case. 
Also, if a key disappears on the next day, as of key3 in the example, I think that it will have no records on 10/2, am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @Sorrow . . . The first query takes the previous version of the record, regardless of the date.  The second insists that the date be one day before.

Comment: here is the sqlfiddle of the second query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/947a4/6. I'm not sure that "1 day preceding" is a valid oracle syntax. As you can see, the key3 record is lost on 10/02, so the the output is not equal to the desired output OutTable. Also I have to filter in an outer query the result in order to get OutTable, which I don't think is that great performance-wise. Thank you again.

Comment: @Sorrow . . . You need to use a subquery if you want to filter.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for the sqlfiddle, although the key3 value is missing from the output as it is not available on 10/2. Is there a way to make it available on 10/2 if it is available on the previous day?

Comment: @Sorrow . . . That doesn't seem to be the question that is asked here.  If you have a different question, it should be asked as a *new* question.

Comment: Actually, it is. I provided a sample input data and a sample output data and specified that missing keys on either date should be kept in the final result. I specifically built the example to show that both key4 and key3, which are missing from 9/2 and 10/2 respectively, are kept in the query results.

Comment: I agree with @Sorrow - the question seemed pretty clear to me, and your solution does not handle it as required. I was able to understand the requirement (and to solve it) without needing any interaction with the OP. Downvoted by me as unhelpful, since it doesn't solve the stated problem. (For example, your own demo is missing the row for `key3` - didn't you notice the discrepancy? I don't see where you asked the OP for clarification about that.)